# Looking for math font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I was trying to reproduce the followings symbols in maths formulas from an old book:

1. [image: image 1]  2) [image: image 2]

At first glance, I thought that `\mathfrak` could do the job, but the result wasn't as expected:

[image: unsuccesfull latex output]

Searching in [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), I found a very similar font that could be useful, called Special Alphabet 1 Monotype

[image: special alphabet 1]

Is there a equivalent math font in `LaTeX` to make these symbols?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{H}\psi &= E\psi \\
\mathfrak{N} &\rightarrow \infty
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't solve your problem but I am eternally grateful for the link WhatTheFont you provided. More than once I spent an evening trying to find back the font what I had used in certain documents a few hard disks before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That H is more similar to Euler Script bold, or perhaps the `\mathcal` font from MathTime Pro.  It would be possible to use that font you found in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Here is a version that uses Neo Euler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \mathbfcal{H} \psi &= E \psi \\
  \mathfrak{N} &\to \infty
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler/New Computer Modern sample]

And a PDFTeX-compatible version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[cal=euler, frak=euler]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \mathbcal{H} \psi &= E \psi \\
  \mathfrak{N} &\to \infty
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: AMS Euler sample]